# JS Image Gallery

Tags: fancybox

I am building a portfolio website and would like to use fancy box to create a simple gallery.

I would like all images from one section to reside inside a single folder ('gallery1') and I would like the user to be able to click through all the images in the folder.

This is my html:

```
<div class="content_image" rel="gallery" href="image01_large.jpg" ><img src="gallery1/image01_small.jpg"/></div>
```

I am trying to use this jQuery script but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("div[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

</script>
```

Any help would be much apreciated!

Comment: Again, this isn't really a code writing service... Such an open ended question may get hate for asking for code to be written for you. Some suggestions: What's wrong with your jQuery script? Why is it not working? Is there some specific aspect of your implementation that you need help with? There are plenty of jQuery gallery plugins online.

Comment: HI Christian! I am really sorry if this comes across as blatant laziness but I am fine with HTML5 and CSS3 but I do not know JavaScript. I was trying to figure it out from various examples online with no luck. 

All the examples I saw use <a> tag but I was able to display a single image using a div. I suspect my syntax 'div[rel=gallery]' where I am trying to target the div is incorrect.

I really spent ages on the site writing my own code. This is the last piece of the puzzle and the first question I am asking. As I said, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are fine with HTML as your said, then you should be writing proper html. The `href` is not a valid attribute for the `<div>` tag, use anchors `<a>` instead.

Comment: What you are looking for is as simple as following the samples provided at http://fancybox.net/howto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of jQuery gallery plugins [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/), updated version [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/jquery-image-2012/).

You want to use a gallery plugin, rather than small bits of script, as they are coded to handle all of the popular browsers as well as work efficiently with finesse. I recommend finding a suitable option there and trying the sample usage for the plugin.

**Edit**

Also try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){$("div[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            })});

</script>
```

Comment: I have the plugin set up- I am using http://fancybox.net

It gives this example-

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>

so I changed my html-

<div class="content_image grouped_elements" rel="gallery" href="image01_large.jpg" ><img src="gallery1/image01_small.jpg"/></div>

and js to-

$("div.grouped_elements").fancybox({... etc.

but it is still not working!? Any suggestions?

Comment: How is it not working? What's it doing? Are you actually including the images that you want to show (image01_large.jpg in the example)?

Comment: When I click there is no pop-up. I checked and paths to images are correct (I can see the small versions but the fancybox does not pop up...)

Comment: Are you including jQuery before the plguin in your script? jQuery plugins must be included with `<script type="text/javascript" src=...` after jQuery is included. This should be the first thing you check.

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct-

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: I tried your last suggestion '$(function(){$("div[rel=gallery]").fancybox({' but still no luck...!?

Comment: Basically what I did was make that code run AFTER the browser has loaded the page completely... Check your JavaScript console, are there any errors?

Comment: As I said, js is my weak spot- tried Firebug Console and when i refresh page there are no errors for javascript. I have Dreamweaver CS6- any better way to check there?

Comment: Firebug should be fine... It's probably a simple problem. The issue is that I really cannot help you without seeing the page... If there's some way to show it on http://jsfiddle.net/ or host it somehow, I can be of more help.

Comment: Here's an error!

TypeError: a is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...xtend(e,w);k=e.title||(a.nodeName?b(a).attr("title"):a.title)||"";if(a.nodeName&...

Comment: Your plugin is outdated, and will not work with whatever version of jQuery you are using. The error is from within the plugin. It could also be something to do with how you've initialized it, again I really cannot tell from what you've given me